# Why do TrueType fonts use only "Quadratic Curves" on the Mac?

Tags: macos, cocoa, core-graphics, core-text, truetype

I extracted the path elements of a TrueType font using the code below.

The problem is that the curves described by `element->type` are only of the type `kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint`, which has 2 points (low quality). Why don't any of the elements use the higher-quality `kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint` type (with 3 points)?

Does anybody have an idea?

```
int count = 0;
void applierFunction(void *info, const CGPathElement *element)
{
    int point_count;
    switch (element->type)
    {
        case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
            point_count = 1;
            break;
        case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
            point_count = 1;
            break;
        case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint:
            point_count = 2;
            break;
        case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint:
            point_count = 3;
            break;
        case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath:
            point_count = 0;
            break;
    }
    count+=point_count;
    printf("%u.:\n", count);
    for (int i = 0; i<point_count; i++) {
        switch (element->type) {
            case kCGPathElementMoveToPoint:
                printf("kCGPathElementMoveToPoint\n");
                break;
            case kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint:
                printf("kCGPathElementAddLineToPoint\n");
                break;
            case kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint:
                printf("kCGPathElementAddQuadCurveToPoint\n");
                break;
            case kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint:
                printf("kCGPathElementAddCurveToPoint\n");
                break;
            case kCGPathElementCloseSubpath:
                printf("kCGPathElementCloseSubpath\n");
                break;
            default:
                printf("unknown path type\n");
        }
    }
}

void extractStringPathElements()
{
    CFStringRef str = CFSTR("Q");
    CFStringRef strFont = CFSTR("Arial");
    CTFontRef font = CTFontCreateWithName(strFont, 500, NULL);
    CFStringRef keys[] = {kCTFontAttributeName};
    CFTypeRef values[] = {font};
    CFDictionaryRef attr = CFDictionaryCreate(NULL, (const void **)&keys,
                                                (const void **)&values, sizeof(keys) / sizeof(keys[0]),
                                                &kCFTypeDictionaryKeyCallBacks, &kCFTypeDictionaryValueCallBacks);
    CFAttributedStringRef attrString =
    CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, str, attr);
    CFRelease(attr);
    CTLineRef line = CTLineCreateWithAttributedString(attrString);
    CFArrayRef runs = CTLineGetGlyphRuns(line);
    long runCount = CFArrayGetCount(runs);
    for (int ri = 0; ri < runCount; ri++) {
        ::CTRunRef run = (::CTRunRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(runs, ri);
        long glyphCount = CTRunGetGlyphCount(run);
        const unsigned short *glyphs = CTRunGetGlyphsPtr(run);
        for (int gi = 0; gi < glyphCount; gi++) {
            ::CGPathRef path = CTFontCreatePathForGlyph(font, glyphs[gi], NULL);
            CGPathApply(path, 0, applierFunction);
            printf("glyph %u has %u elements.\n", glyphs[gi], count);
            CGPathRelease(path);
        }
    }
    CFRelease(line);
    CFRelease(attrString);
    CFRelease(font);

}

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    extractStringPathElements();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

TrueType has no cubic bezier curves. It's limited to quadratic bezier curves. TrueType was specified that way.

Comment: Is this about only mac? In Windows I extracted 68 points for same character and font which contains bezier curves, but In Mac 42 points extracted.

Comment: No, this isn't Mac specific. That's the same on all platforms. If you had a cubic bezier curve on Windows, then it wasn't a TrueType font but rather an OpenType font (which support cubic beziers).